# validation in model and viewmodel mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a domain model which has 10 fields in it.
I have 5 views with different fields from this model(Each view having a different set of fields). For this purpose, I created a ViewModel for each view(total 5 ViewModels).

My question is in every view model I have to duplicate the validation logic. Is there any simple approach to avoid validation logic duplicating for every ViewModel?

Below is how my models and ViewModels look like.

```
public class Student {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(15)]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Range(5,12)]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    [Range(0,1000)]
    public int MarksObtained { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}


public class StudentDetailsViewModel {
    //validation duplicated for each field
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(15)]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}


public class StudentMarksViewModel
{
    //validation duplicated for each field
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Range(5, 12)]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 1000)]
    public int MarksObtained { get; set; }
}
```

So I do not want my validation logic duplicated everywhere. I want a centralized validation logic and my ViewModels to use them without mentioning everywhere.

Comment: You could try to validate your model

Comment: Put your validation into attributes then place them in annotations in your viewmodel

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of how you are currently validating your models?

Comment: Hi @DionV. I added the code how I am currently doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

Let every `ViewModel`Inherit from a `BaseModel` and have the validation logic there.

**Your Base Model**

```
public class VM_Student //Your Base
{
  //Only include Attributes here that you need every time.
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [StringLength(50)]
  public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

**Your ViewModels**

```
public class VM_StudentFull : VM_Student
{
  //Only Add the Extra Fields here, the StudentFull inherits
  //the other attributes and validation
  [StringLength(15)]
  [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
  public string Mobile { get; set; }
  [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
  public string Email { get; set; }
  [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
  public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }          
}

public class VM_StudentMarks : VM_Student
{
  //Only Add the Extra Fields here again,
  //the StudentMarks inherits the other attributes and validation
  [Range(5,12)]
  public int ClassId { get; set; }
  [Range(0,1000)]
  public int MarksObtained { get; set; }
  [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]           
}
```

This is just a quick example, of course you'd need to match it to your solution accordingly.
Sort out the attributes you need in every `ViewModel`, and plainly add them to the new `ViewModel`.

Comment: Can you explain with a small example?

Comment: @aditya Sure, if you can include some code snippets in question, I can provide a short example

Comment: What does public bool validationMethod()  mean? A separate method? How can I validate my fields in this method?

Comment: @aditya See the answer now. Before was just a blind guess on what your code looks like. I now included your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103302/discussion-between-print-x-div-0-and-aditya).